# jquery .children() returning wrong size

Tags: jquery, size, children

I just found the children size not consistent.

Below attach full code with alert, for easy reference.

Is the way I get the data wrong?

```
<body>
<table width="100" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
      <tr>
        <td height="30" valign="top"><strong>Header Title</strong></td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
          <td height="32" valign="top">Date : <strong>01/01/2010 </strong> <br><div><b></b></div><span></span></td>
      </tr>
</table>
</body>
```

---

```
$("td").each(function() {
    alert($(this).children().size());   
});

//first td showing 1 direct children- <strong>
//second td showing 4 direct children- <strong> <br> <div> <span>

-----

$("tr").each(function() {
    alert($(this).children().size());   
});

//first tr showing 1 direct children - <td>
//second tr showing 1 direct children - <td>

-----

$("table").each(function() {
    alert($(this).children().size());   
});

// ERROR
// this table showing 1 direct children only.... something WRONG.
// I thought there are 2 <tr> inside this table?
```

Comment: by the way, what are you trying to count? the rows in the table? just do a $("tr").length then. or if you have many tables, add an id to your table and access it as $("#tableid tr")

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason is that you don't have a `<tbody>` within your table. The browser adds this automatically for you, and hence it becomes the only child of `<table>`.

You may be interested in running this piece of code:

```
alert($('table').children()[0].tagName);
```

Comment: this is a bit tricky. What if certain browser never help you to add in tbody. Then it will be cross browser issue already.

Comment: @i need help, the best option is to always include `<tbody>` yourself in the HTML.

Answer (score 0):

You're asking the size of the td's children, and in your structure, your td only has one child: the strong tag.

In your second, you are asking the children of your trs. Each of your tr tags only have 1 td, thus it is showing 1 only.

Try  this:

```
alert($("tbody").children().length)
```

Comment: inside td got strong, br, div and span at the same level. How do you know strong is children, others in the same level not consider children?

Comment: as you said in your question above, the first td only had 1 strong tag. and the second one with all the others are considered children thats why it alerted 4.